# Datetime being rendered 1 hour off when sent as part of the context variable to a Django template

Tags: python, django, datetime

I'm passing a timezone-aware python `datetime` to a Django template as part of the context variable.  Printing out the `datetime` object directly before rendering the template, I get the following value:

```
2014-08-04 04:00:00-04:00
```

However, when the datetime is actually rendered as part of the Django template, I get the following value:

```
Aug. 4, 2014, 3 a.m.
```

Based on the value I'm printing out from my view in python, I'm expecting a 4 am value, but 3 am is actually getting rendered.

Here is the code I am using to create that datetime, based on passed in year/month/day/hour/minute.

```
dt = datetime.datetime(year, month, day, hour, minutes, 0)          
dt = pytz.timezone("America/Toronto").localize(dt)
```

Why is this happening and how can I resolve it?

Comment: First thing that comes to mind is daylight saving time offset. What time zones are you using?

Comment: @AndrewArnold I thought the same thing.  EST ("America/Toronto" with pytz).

Comment: Well, it's EDT right now, not EST. That might be a problem.

Comment: @AndrewArnold Sorry, that's a communication error on my behalf.  Given year/month/day/hour/minutes, I'm creating the datetime object as such: `dt = datetime.datetime(year, month, day, hour, minutes, 0)
   dt = pytz.timezone("America/Toronto").localize(dt)`

Answer (score -3):

the problem seems to be   [timezone](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/i18n/timezones/) change the TIME_ZON  e